# Google Map does not work in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show map of my university but it load for 1 sec and then tell

**MissingKeyMapError**

and

**Sorry! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.**

I use Google Maps JavaScript API and Web browser (javaScript).Hear is my code :

```
    <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDNi7fQreXQ_AvjDEbMBGtBo2XoP5QkxRs'></script>
    <div style='overflow:hidden;height:440px;width:700px;'>
        <div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:440px;width:700px;'></div>
        <style>#gmap_canvas img {
            max-width: none !important;
            background: none !important
        }       </style>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function init_map() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.3475365, 91.81233240000006),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.3475365, 91.81233240000006)
            });
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<strong>University of Chittagong</strong><br>Chittagong , Bangladesh<br>'});
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
    </script>
</head>
```

This is my full code . Please help me for my project.

Comment: wrong google map api key

Comment: @Vishnu Bhadoriya wrong google map api key means what?

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Key=AIzaSyDNi7fQreXQ_AvjDEbMBGtBo2XoP5QkxRs

Comment: @Vishnu Bhadoriya Now i use new API Key from google . But same problem. What now i do?

Comment: First off all, your code have big mistakes, look at here [how to use google map info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple). In addition, you wrote `Key`, change it to `key` , I corrected your code but I couldn't answer yet. Answer is closed before I published :(

Comment: Btw, change it you wrote - `google.maps.MapTypeI;` and didn't close `myOptions` with `{braces}` 
var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.3475365, 91.81233240000006),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

Comment: @Teymur Mardaliyer Lennon Same problem :(

Comment: @user3291513 can you write me in private?

Comment: @user3291513 please check edit, it worked for me.

Comment: @Teymur Mardaliyer Lennon how to check edit or write private ! I am a new user ;(

Comment: @Teymur Mardaliyer Lennon it's work . Thank's ;)

Comment: @user3291513 you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that key? Like Vishnu said, that should be the problem. If you did not get it from the Google Maps API documentation you should go there and get a new one (they are accessible for free). Also, the title of your question seems misleading in my opinion, as you do not seem to use PHP.

Comment: Now i use new API Key from google . But same problem

Comment: It can take a couple of minutes before it works. This error shouldn't be thrown for any other problem as far as I know, if you signed up for your API key correctly then either it should work or some other error will be thrown.